# ConcurrentModificationException *after* modifying ArrayList

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I'm working on some code and during testing it started throwing a ConcurrentModificationException. After some research, what confuses me is that I'm not adding or removing from the list while iterating. I do iterate over the list, but it's after I've added to the list. To add clarity, below is a commented version of the code:

```
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        ConfigurationManager manager = new ConfigurationManager(f);
        //The next line uses the same thread to get all Host objects from the file
        ArrayList<Host> configHosts = manager.getAllHosts();
        //Add the found hosts to a (previously established) ArrayList
        hosts.addAll(configHosts);
        for(Host h : hosts) { //Exception thrown points to this line.
            //This reads values from the Host object and puts them in a JTable.
            //No modification is done to the object, it is just read from.
            this.updateTable(h);
        }
```

I'm not sure how this code could possibly throw the ConcurrentModificationException, unless addAll() operates in a different thread (and then updateTable() would be called as hosts were still being added). But saving that, I'm not sure what I'm doing that's inappropriate.

Comment: What exactly is the place where the exception is thrown?

Comment: What is `hosts`? Is it a field on the class this code is from? If so, could this field be accessed by other classes or threads?

Comment: Is the exception caused by addAll or updateTable?

Comment: On the for loop line. I'll update the post accordingly.

Comment: Then `updateTable` modifies `hosts`... **or** there's a ghost in the machine.

Comment: @andersschuller yes it's a field, but there are no other threads/classes running when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @Steven the exception points to the initialization of the `for` loop, so I would assume updateTable() is the cause, but I'm not sure as it only reads data from a host object.

Comment: Could it be that `ConfigurationManager` has some internal caching and that, in testing, this class is used from two threads? In other words, either you have overlooked some very important aspect of your code, or we'd better start looking for *really* exotic explanations.

Comment: Could you post the updateTable method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug in my code. The commentators were right; updateTable() was (indirectly) responsible. There's a special case where certain hosts will be removed from the global field, and my test data just had to hit this special case. I'm not deleting the question because I believe there's value in my specific error. In short, if you get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, check the following:

- Are you trying to remove/add an item from an ArrayList while  iterating over the list?
- Are you sure code that is reading the ArrayList side effect free (i.e. it won't modify the list under any case) (this was my problem)?
- Are you working in a multithreaded environment where this ArrayList could be modified during your iteration (if so, you might want to `synchronize` the loop)?

Comment: You could also iterate over your list using an Iterator list.listIterator().  Then loop over the Iterator using a while loop using iterator.hasNext() and iterator.next() inside the loop.  If you need to remove a Host from the list, keep track of the index the iterator is at and remove that index from the list inside your while loop.  In my experience, that solves the ConcurrentModificationException.